# Google Apps Script Gmail Invalid email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am using Google Apps Script to send emails. I do this via `Thread.reply` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply(String,Object).

This works for most contacts however I have faced issues when the contact's email address contains non-ascii characters.

So before sending mail, I'd check whether the first messages's sender in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom is a string with only ascii characters - and then skipped those. This made the error disappear. This however resulted in a lot of emails not being sent because even when the email address didn't contain any non-ascii characters, any character like `é` in the senders name (not email) would make my script skip that contact.

So I went ahead and only checked whether the literal email address between `<` and `>` is ascii. This ran well for weeks because now even if the name contained e.g. French characters, it would still send the email (given that the email address was ascii) without issues as we only need to check the email address for ascii.

Today, the script threw with 2 emails. It said `Invalid email` on the `.reply` call. The emails (HIGHLY MODIFIED FOR ANONYMITY) look like this:

`"\"SB XXXX.\"" <sb.1XXXXX@icloud.com>`

`"XXXX" <splXXXX@icloud.com>`

Is this an issue on Gmail's side? The email addresses themselves look perfectly valid without any special characters in them. It now seems to be the name that breaks the whole thing.

I think I could alternatively "manually" send a new email in my script, so I am not bound to the `Thread.reply` function however this is less comfortable as it requires me to manually specify things like `In-Reply-To` and `References` so the email would show up in threaded views in mail clients etc.

Comment: Don't use a filter.  Instead use a try/catch and if it fails record it in a list and skip it.

Comment: I do try/catch but that of course leads to the email not being sent. I'd much prefer to fix the actual cause of the issue rather than to make the code simply ignore entries

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a character set issue.

Comment: I am fairly sure it is, however there doesn't seem to be a way to set that anywhere